# Why is the MYSQL error "Cannot add foreign key constraint" showing?

Tags: mysql

I am currently working through my MySQL task and have come across a small hiccup whilst using foreign keys. The problem is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
student_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
subject_name INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
exam_date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (exam_date),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES  student (student_id),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_name) REFERENCES subject (subject_name));
```

After i enter this code Error 1215 pops up saying that i cannot add foreign key constraints. The error is shown below:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

The table i am trying to link the  foreign key is this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subjects(
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
level_of_entry VARCHAR(20),
exam_board VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(student_id));
```

I have no issues with this table and simply wonder how i could solve my dilemma?

Comment: First create both table student and subject, then create  entries table. And be care about typo (FOREIGN KEY (subject_name) REFERENCES subject (subject_name));) Here you are adding student and created table students.

Answer (score 2):

You have subject_name INT(10) in one table and subject_name VARCHAR(20) in the other
Doublecheck types, when creating foreign keys in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you this has fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`entries` table `subject_name` is of datatype `int` where as in subjects table the datatype of `subject_name` is `varchar`.
in order to add a foreign key constraint the 2 datatypes must match

Comment: So by fixing this i would simply change the code subject_name to subject_id?